# How to Embed a p5js Sketch in a React Project Using react-script-tag and react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to embed a p5js sketch in a React project. I am using react-script-tag to embed the .js file which contains the p5js sketch and I am using react-router-dom to manage the routes to the webpages. I have managed to get the p5js sketch displaying properly, however I am facing the following issue:

The ScriptTag referencing the p5js sketch is located within within the Route to '/p5js'.

```
<Route path="/p5js" element={<p5js />}/>
```

The p5js sketch only loads after I've refreshed the browser on that page, 'localhost:3000/p5js'. Once it loads, it remains on the screen even after I go to back to another page, say

```
<Route path="/home" element={<Home />}/>
```

How I can have the p5js sketch appear automatically when navigating to the p5js page? And how can I have the sketch disappear when navigating to new pages, such as the 'Home' page?

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import SQL from "./pages/SQL";
import SuperCollider from "./pages/SuperCollider";
import p5js from "./pages/p5js";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/sql" element={<SQL />} />
          <Route path="/sc" element={<SuperCollider />} />
          <Route path="/p5js" element={<p5js />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

p5js.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ScriptTag from 'react-script-tag';

const p5js = () =>{
    return (
      <div className="p5js">
      <ScriptTag type="text/javascript" src="sketch2.js" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default p5js;
```

Comment: You might want to look into using [react-p5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5) or similar to convert your p5 code into a compatible React component.

Comment: Thanks Drew. I think I might have to go this route. I just tested with an example react-p5 component, and it is working as expected. Still not sure why I'm having the issue when embedding the p5js sketch, but this should do the trick.

Comment: Update: I just got the sketch converted to using react-p5 and still am facing the same issues.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this routing/navigation issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 1):

I use [react-p5-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5-wrapper) to use p5 as a component and have had similar issues with the p5 instance hanging around, consuming touch events and such.

I've found it useful to use p5's `remove()`  function. Listen for a location change then call [remove](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/remove) as needed.

Haven't had any issue with p5 not appearing / running when it's wrapper component is rendered.